# Capitalization/Proper use of apostrophe for omitted letters at start of quotation

Tags: capitalization, apostrophe, quotation-marks

Suppose I have a character who can’t pronounce the letter *b,* and I have him start a sentence with “bananas” in dialogue.

Is this correct, using a single quotation mark in front of *a* pointing away from *a:*

> “’ananas! What will I do now?” Arun said.

Should I capitalize the *a* of “ananas”? It’s at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: To avoid the cluster of quote ticks, I might use an em-dash without capitalizing the *a*. I think consistency throughout the narrative's dialog is important. You don't want the reader to start hesitating while they figure out what you're trying to express.

Comment: In a restaurant in France once, my father assumed that 'Ananas' on a menu was an error for 'bananas'. He didn't get _bananas au kirsch_, but something else.

Comment: Ananas are pineapples, not bananas.:)

Comment: tchrist - yes, I know that. That was _the whole point of my little story_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you use an apostrophe to show missing letters that have been contracted out of the beginning of a word for whatever reason, you still use a capital first letter for the sentence, meaning you'd use a capital *A*. A common example we see is in answer to a question of *why* when someone answers with a form of *because* where they've omitted the *be* at the beginning.

**Examples from published works:**

> ['Cause](https://books.google.com/books?id=nE5KsECeNLYC&pg=PA144&dq=%22%27cause%20I%20don%27t%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSkrfFobPkAhVDMqwKHThbAroQ6AEIWzAH#v=onepage&q=%22'cause%20I%20don't%22&f=false) I don't think he go to Placerville or Sacramento.

-*Corbett Mack: The Life of a Northern Paiute* by Michael Hittman, pg. 144

> ['Cause](https://books.google.com/books?id=pZf9Hk-3NysC&pg=PA62&dq=%22%27cause%20I%20don%27t%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSkrfFobPkAhVDMqwKHThbAroQ6AEIYjAI#v=onepage&q=%22'cause%20I%20don't%22&f=false) I don't wanna be involved in nothin' that goes on around
>   there.

-*Getting Played: African American Girls, Urban Inequality, and Gendered Violence* by Jody Miller, pg. 62

> ['Cause](https://books.google.com/books?id=xvNAX7lye6oC&pg=PA76&dq=%22%27cause%20I%20don%27t%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSkrfFobPkAhVDMqwKHThbAroQ6AEIaTAJ#v=onepage&q=%22'cause%20I%20don't%22&f=false) I don't care.

-*Misadventure: Monologues and Short Pieces* by Donald Marguiles, pg. 76

Answer (score 0):

Capitalization is a marker of the beginning of a sentence. I'd capitalize the A to avoid confusion. The apostrophe should be enough to let the reader know the B is missing.

Comment: "'Allo", said the Cockney.

Comment: We are to use "comments" in such cases. This doesn't qualify for an answer.